# How to fold few selected lines of code in PyCharm IDE?

Tags: pycharm, code-cleanup, folding

How can i fold few selected lines of code in PyCharm Ide.

For eg, i want to fold this selected lines of code shown in the image below:

[image]

```
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found Solution to this!!

Steps:

1. Select the lines of code you want to fold and press `CTRL + .`( Ctrl + Dot).

OR

2. Right click and navigate to Folding -> click on 'Fold Selection/Remove Region' option.

Screenshot:
[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: for macOS users, `CMD + .` is the shortcut :)

Answer (score 1):

Command (Cmd) . (dot) on a Mac